# How to set on click listener in LinearLoyout ImageView

Tags: android, android-linearlayout, onclicklistener

I can't handle Listnerer on `ImageView` inisde `LinearLayout`
i've been trying
`andorid:clickable`
`andorid:focusable`

`onTouchListener`

change type to `AppCompactImageView`

i don't know if there is a problem with fragment  or other but i can't do anything .

here is my 
Loyout code

```
<ScrollView
....
<LinearLayout
....
        <LinearLayout
            android:paddingTop="15dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/mail_icon_about"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ikona_maila"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mail"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_mail" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/facebook_icon_about"
                android:layout_width="60dp"
                android:layout_height="60dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ikona_facebook"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_facebook"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_facebook" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/website_icon_about"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/ikona_website"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_website"
                tools:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_website" />

        </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>


</ScrollView>
```

here is my code ( it's fragment ) :P

```
    public class AboutFragment extends Fragment implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView mailImage;
    ImageView faceBookImage;
    ImageView webSiteImage;


    public AboutFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_about, container, false);

        mailImage=view.findViewById(R.id.mail_icon_about);
        faceBookImage=view.findViewById(R.id.facebook_icon_about);
        webSiteImage=view.findViewById(R.id.website_icon_about);

        mailImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        faceBookImage.setOnClickListener(this);
        webSiteImage.setOnClickListener(this);

        return view;
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.mail_icon_about:
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("About","1");
                break;
            case R.id.facebook_icon_about:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("About","2");
                break;
            case R.id.website_icon_about:
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "3", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("About","3");
                break;
        }

    }
```

Comment: What does happen? Did you try button a breakpoint on the line with the `switch ...`?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ImageButton instead of ImageView

Comment: @GagatekPawel Then you should check whether any parent view intercept the click event. As the 'looks' you mentioned, you can change the imagebutton's background res to make it looks like an image instead of an ugly default button. But using ImageView or ImageButton isn't the key point now

Answer (score 0):

In the Activity.java referring to that XML file create an ImageView:

```
ImageView imageview = findViewById(R.id.idofyourimageview);
```

Then set a click listener:

```
imageview.setOnClickListener(new View.onClickListener(){
     @Override
     public void onClick(View v){
          //your code
     }
});
```

Comment: I have always written the code exactly like the one shown above (I'm talking about the one I wrote) in order to get clickable images, and IT WORKS, you just set the Click Listener.

Comment: In the code you wrote, you didn't create an onClickListener by passing to the constructor a View.onClickListener